# IBM BladeCenter H networking

Tags: networking, virtualization, ibm, bladecenter

I'm new to the IBM BladeCenter H, and I'm trying to figure out the networking side of it.

I've installed a windows server OS on one of the blades, and am trying to fiddle with it's network setup (specifically in order to allow it to join an existing hyper-v failover cluster)

The BladeCenter has two ethernet modules and two fibre modules.  I can access all of these via their web interfaces.  However, I cannot figure out how they link up.  Perhaps I'm going about it all wrong.

My assumption is that the Chassis can serve NIC ports up to the blade, and I figured that I could mix and match from the interface for the ethernet modules.  But I either cannot, or cannot figure out how to.

So let me pose this as a question:  if I needed to give another NIC to a blade, how would I do that?

Any IBM BladeCenter heroes out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type of blade you have and how it is configured, it will have a certain number of physical nics inside of it.  You cannot give it more, other than by installing additional mezzanine cards in the blade.

Certain types of nics do support partitioning, which is the ability to logically divide the physical nic into multiple logical nics, that appear to the OS as separate devices.  This would be done by going into the BIOS (i.e. for an Emulex nic, by typing ctrl-E during the appropriate point in the boot sequence).

Each physical nic in the blade is connected inside the chassis to a given port on one of your Ethernet switches.  This is not something you can change.

All of this is probably unrelated to your issue of joining your hyper-v cluster.  If you have a working network connection, you should be able to get there.  That of course depends on your server having the appropriate connectivity (meaning the right vlans, routing, etc.) to join the cluster.